# Reverting a linear filter for time series in R

Tags: r, filter, signal-processing

I'm using the `stats::filter` function in R in order to understand ARIMA simulations in R (as in the function `stats::arima.sim`) and estiamtion. I know that `stats::filter` applies a linear filter to a vector or time series, but I'm not sure how to "unfilter" my series.

Consider the following example: I want to use a recursive filter with value `0.7` to my series `x = 1:5` (which is essentially generating an AR(1) with phi=0.7). I can do so by:

```
x    <- 1:5 
ar   <-0.7 
filt <- filter(x, ar, method="recursive")
filt 

Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 5 
Frequency = 1 
[1]  1.0000  2.7000  4.8900  7.4230 10.1961
```

Which returns me essentially `c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)` where:

```
y1 <- x[1]                                            
y2 <- x[2] + ar*y1      
y3 <- x[3] + ar*y2 
y4 <- x[4] + ar*y3 
y5 <- x[5] + ar*y4
```

Now imagine I have the `y = c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)` series. How can I use the filter function to return me the original series `x = 1:5`?

I can write a code to do it like:

```
unfilt <- rep(NA, 5)
unfilt[1] <- filt[1]

for(i in 2:5){
   unfilt[i] <- filt[i] - ar*filt[i-1]
}
unfilt
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But I do want to use the filter function to do so, instead of writing my own function. How can I do so? I tried `stats::filter(filt, -ar, method="recursive")`, which returns me `[1] 1.0000 2.0000 3.4900 4.9800 6.7101` not what I desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stats::filter` used with the `recursive` option is a particular case of an `ARMA` filter.

```
a[1]*y[n] + a[2]*y[n-1] + … + a[n]*y[1] = b[1]*x[n] + b[2]*x[m-1] + … + b[m]*x[1]
```

You could implement this filter with the `signal` package which allows more options than `stat::filter` :

```
a = c(1,-ar)
b = 1

filt_Arma <- signal::filter(signal::Arma(b = b, a = a),x)
filt_Arma

# Time Series:
# Start = 1 
# End = 5 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1]  1.0000  2.7000  4.8900  7.4230 10.1961

identical(filt,filt_Arma)
# [1] TRUE
```

Reverting an `ARMA` filter can be done by switching `b` and `a`, provided that the inverse filter stays stable (which is the case here):

```
signal::filter(signal::Arma(b = a, a = b),filt)

# Time Series:
# Start = 2 
# End = 6 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

This corresponds to switching numerator and denominator in the [z-transform](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/filter-implementation-and-analysis.html):

```
Y(z) = a(z)/b(z) X(z)

X(z) = b(z)/a(z) Y(z)
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response! But using the package stats::filter, how could I get the same result? I also tried using ```method="convolution"``` with ```sides=2``` to revert it, but seems like the operation is more complex

Comment: AFAIK, `stat::filter` doesn't allow to specify numerator & denominator of filter z-transform, that's why I used `signal::filter` which allows filter operations I'm used to in Matlab.